# How to force a re-render of a hook from a parent component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two files:

1. App.js
2. useFetch.js

useFetch.js is a custom hook that i want to use to do requests to certain API using fetch.

This is the content of App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useFetch from './hooks/useFetch';
...
const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, error, setUrl, isLoading, abort] = useFetch();

  const handleAction = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      abort();
      console.log('abort signal sended');
    } else {
      setUrl(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <div
          className="App-header-button"
        >
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color={isLoading ? 'secondary' : 'primary'}
            onClick={() => handleAction()}
          >
            {isLoading ? 'Cancel' : 'Test'}
          </Button>
        </div>
        {data && 'Data loaded'}
        <input type="text" onChange={event => setPage(event.target.value)} value={page} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As you can see, is a simple app. The input on the end is using to set the page to display from the API.

This is the content of my custom useFetch.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

  const useFetch = (defaultUrl) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(defaultUrl);
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [controller] = useState(new AbortController());

  const { signal } = controller;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      fetch(url, { signal })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res.data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err);
          console.log(err.name);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }, [url]);

  const abort = () => {
    controller.abort();
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return [
    data,
    error,
    setUrl,
    isLoading,
    abort,
  ];
};

export default useFetch;
```

I have one problem here... this works very good and display the data when i change the page and hit the button. The problem is: If i push the button with the page and hit the button again with the same page, nothing happens. This have certain sense because the url aren't change, still be the same data sended to the hook. Suppose the user wants to refresh the data with the same page hitting the button again. On this case i need the hook makes again the same call repeating the same url. So how can I do to force the hook to 'render' it again?

**[UPDATE I]**

With the help of @Atul i made this changes and works. I only wonder if this is a good way or the most appropriate way to achieve this.

On useFetch.js:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (url && refreshFlag) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      fetch(url, { signal })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res.data);
          setIsLoading(false);
          setRefreshFlag(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err);
          console.log(err.name);
          setRefreshFlag(false);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }, [url, refreshFlag]);
```

On App.js: (only showing the code of the button action)

```
  const handleAction = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      abort();
      console.log('abort signal sended');
    } else {
      refresh(true);
      setUrl(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`);
    }
  };
```

Comment: you can send refresh flag and make useEffect as useEffect(func) [url,refreshFlag]. Whenever you want to refresh just send different value in flag or just toggle the flag value so it will be different from the existing value and useEffect will execute the api.

Comment: Maybe you could extrapolate the contents of your useEffect to a function that you can call on demand and then return that function along with the rest of your data. You'd still of course call that function inside your useEffect

Comment: @KhauriMcClain can you please give me a little sample to see how this works? Thanks my friend.

Comment: @Atul i just try your method an it works... i just wonder if this is a best practice.. but is great! i will update the question with your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know that @Atul alread gave you a solution to this problem,
and I used this to also make things work in my code,
but not all is said here and I needed to think about it a bit, how to implement it,

So I'll write this answer to make this simpler for other guys which will visit this page.
Keep in mind that credits goes to @Atul :)

I will list what changes needs to be done in code above to make it work.

First, in `useFetch.ts`, you want to:

1. add new state
   `const [refreshFlag, setRefreshFlag] = useState(true)`
2. add a function which triggers the refresh
   `const refresh = () => {setRefreshFlag(true)}`
3. then you want to 'export' this function, not the state, so the `return` part of `useFetch.ts` should look like this:

```
  return [
    data,
    error,
    setUrl,
    isLoading,
    abort,
    refresh, // added this
  ];
```

4. You want your `useEffect` to depend on the `refreshFlag`, and you already have that.
   One thing to change to make the code nicer is, instead of doing `setIsLoading(false);` and `setRefreshFlag(false);` in both `try` and `catch`, you can insted do it one time - in `finally`

Now, in `App.js`:

A) You want to use `refresh()` in place where you have `refresh(true);`

B) You haven't put in the code above that you also need to destructure `refresh` from `useFetch`, so change
`const [data, error, setUrl, isLoading, abort] = useFetch();` to
`const [data, error, setUrl, isLoading, abort, refresh] = useFetch();`

--------------- Below is a tip not realated to answer, -------------------
--------------- just something what imo makes the code cleaner ------------

Something to add - this is a matter of taste, but I personally dont like destructuring things like you did from `useFetch`. Reasons are:

- when you will have two API requests in one component, you will need to create unique names for variables from those hooks
- when you see in code `refresh` you don't know that it's the function from API, you need to spend time (few seconds, but always something) to get that info

Instead what I do is make a variable for the hook inside component:
`const fetch = useFetch()`
(this `useFetch` name is bad example, in practice you will have something like
`const getUsers = useGetUsers()`),
and then you will use, in your code, `getUsers.data`, `getUsers.isLoading` etc.